# insert xul element into browser so it scrolls with it

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to insert an xul element into the gBrowser.selectedBrowser element so that this xul element scrolls with the document node.

I used this code to create and add a box:

```
var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
var panel = win.document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul','box');
var props = {
    style: 'width:300px;height:100px;background-color:red;'
}
for (var p in props) {
    panel.setAttribute(p, props[p]);
}

gBrowser.selectedBrowser.appendChild(panel);
```

problem is that the box is not seen anywhere. it is in the dom inspection though:

[image]

Comment: Try adding it outside the browser element, not inside. browser acts similar to an iframe, it probably does not render its child elements.

Comment: Thanks @the8472 I tried doing that and it doesn't scroll with the document :(

Comment: You will have to scroll it manually via javascript. Otherwise you would have to insert it as anonymous node inside the document itself.

Comment: Ah thats a good idea I didnt think anon node within document would work. So if it's anonymous we can throw xul into an html document?

Comment: Eh no, I think that won't work since XUL is not allowed in content anymore, only in chrome. So you either have to align things via JS or inject into content directly

Comment: Thanks man can you please explain what you mean by inject into content direclty? Do you mean instead of xul use html, inject html direclty (as xul is not injectable?)?

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in the comments above the issue is that the `<browser>` element does not render its contents, similar to an `<iframe>`.

Your options to have the box scroll with the content are
a) reposition your box via javascript on scroll events
b) build the HTML equivalent of your box and inject it into the content directly. If the page content is untrusted you have to consider security concerns into accounts since it could manipulate the DOM used by your addon.